# "If you are a bird I am a bird" VS "If you were a bird I ...." which is right?

Tags: conditionals

Why "If you are a bird I am a bird" is right?
In my case "If you were a bird, I would be a bird" or "If you were a bird I will kill you" are right. Please tell more detailed about it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Are" is a present-tense form of the verb *to be*. So saying "If you *are* a bird..." is an observation about what a person *is now*:

> If you *are* a bird then I must be a bird.

Although nonsensical, it is following the logic that you and the other person are the same, so if the other person *is* something, you must be the same.

"Were" is a past-tense form of the verb *to be*, however, *it is also used to hypothesize about something that might happen*. This usage is normally recognisable by the conditional "if".

You might say:

> If I were a bird I would fly away.

This is a purely whimsical statement - saying that *if* you were a bird, hypothetically you would fly away. There is no logic here.

This doesn't really work with your example statement, because it cannot be "logical":

> If I were a bird, then you would be a bird.

Your *hypothetically* being a bird does not dictate that someone else would be one too. I think for this example you need "*If you are....*".

Your other example though is not about logic:

> "If you were a bird I will kill you"

This is entirely hypothetical because it is about what you would do if another condition was met (the other person was a bird). The only thing wrong with this example is that, when speaking about a hypothetical *future*, "will" should be "*would*":

> If you were a bird I *would* kill you.